# localizedFailureReason returns null

Tags: ios, nserror

I need to show error localizedFailureReason for some reason. I am getting NSError

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unexpected end of file while parsing object.) UserInfo=0x178a72b80 {NSDebugDescription=Unexpected end of file while parsing object.}
```

when I try to log

```
[error localizedFailureReason]
```

I am getting null value for this. May I know what caused this? I am only getting

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)
```

for

```
[error localizedDescription]  only
```

Below is my complete code for the method:

```
+(NSDictionary *)insertErrorIntoFormat:(NSError*)error{

NSLog(@"1.%@",[error localizedDescription]);
NSLog(@"2.%@",[error description]);
NSLog(@"3.%@",[self getCurrentDateTimeString]);

NSDictionary *threat = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [self getCurrentDateTimeString], kTimestamp,
                        [error localizedDescription], @"logs",
                        [error localizedFailureReason], @"reason",
                        nil];


   return threat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSError isn't required to have a failure reason string. It's perfectly valid for it to return `nil`. You need to check the return value before you add it to an NSDictionary or NSArray since those data structures cannot contain a nil value.